# How to make independent a function on different target jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't realy know if this is where the problem come from but it seems to be that the event of `stopPropagation()`is applying to both div at a time.

A bit of explanation : So I have a div "`.customSelect`" that display herself only if you click on a link "`.custom-select`".
The main problem is that when I told it to close it self if I click on the body, it open an other div (which has the same class but still shouldn't).

*What is the best way to make them be independent ?*

This is the code and **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/Baldrani/h9zs62da/17/)** is a link to the Fiddle.

```
$('.custom-select').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).next($('.customSelect')).toggle(350);
});

$('body').click(function(e){
    $('.customSelect').toggle(350);
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just use `.hide()` instead of `.toggle()` for the body click handler.

Answer (score 2):

Use this to hide only the visible ones when you click away.

```
$('body').click(function(e){
    $('.customSelect:visible').toggle(350);
});
```

Comment: Hum yeah very well tough :)